# Recursively building a hex grid

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree

For a fun side project, I've been trying to build a tool that generates a "tonal latus", which is basically a hex grid like this one: [image]

Just to add entertainment I want to generate this grid recursively. So basically a Node will have 6 children which are stored in an array (the 0th index being the left or westernmost child and then going clockwise).

The problem I'm having with this is the recursive function finding out if a child already exists as part of another nodes creation and if so add the existing node to the child array instead of creating a new node as the child.

I've tried is giving each node a fake "x-y" id and passing an array as part of the recursion to look up to see if something exists which works for the most part but doesn't scale, I feel like there is a clever way of generating this that I'm missing. Has anyone come across a problem like this?

Comment: I think you just want to make an array=[], add your base element and use whatever function to find it's children. Then for each child, do the same and add the child and it's children, add those children and their children, etc. recursively so long as they don't already exist in the array. It sounds like from your description that you want to use a tree but that doesn't seem like it's the proper tool to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a coordinate system like this.

[image]

So each grid (x, y) is connected to (x-1, y), (x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1), (x+1, y), (x+1, y-1) and (x, y-1).